# json_encode php

Tags: ajax

Отправляю форму Ajax. На сервер все доходит, но на PHP обработчике встроены ошибки, которые не могу перекодировать и отправить обратно.

Форма:

```
    function register()

$.post( "/index.php",{'username': $('#user').val(),'email' : $('#emailr').val(), 'password' : $('#passwordr').val(),'passwordConfirm' : $('#password_confirmation').val(), 'submit' :'Register',  },
     function( data ) {
            if(data == 1){ 
             $("#err").html("Все ОК");

            } else {
                $("#err").html("Не ОК");

                return false;
```

PHP

```
if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 3){
        $error[] = 'Логин короткий.';

    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Как отправить `$error[]`?

Answer (score 0):

Из PHP передать данные в виде JSON

```
print json_encode($error);
exit();
```

или

```
exit( json_encode($error) );
```

На стороне js получить данные через точку:

```
success: function(data) {
    console.log( data );
    alert( data.ключ );
}
```

Comment: )) Увидел ответ сервера,

Comment: Проблема , что в консоль приходит нормальный ответ, а в алерт закодированный консоль похоже закодированный

Comment: ["\u041f\u0430\u0440\u043e\u043b\u044c \u043a\u043e\u0440\u043e\u0442\u043a\u0438\u0439."]